# Is there a standard way to parse a log file to find sensitive information if any?

Tags: java, logging

We have to send our daily application logs to external vendors sometimes for analyzing.
We don't log credit cards or other information in the log file. But we are not sure if the log contains any sensitive information of company secrets.
We will have to find out a way to search them and mask them in the log file before sending it out of network.

Right now I am keeping on browsing through the logs to see if any information should be masked and updating the regex registry for masking.

Now I understand that this is company specific information and there is no way out off the manual checking process.
But is there a standard dictionary sort of, which covers the common patterns?
Or could anybody suggest an approach for me to create one?

Comment: Use a regex to find and remove emailadresses and IP addresses and URLs

Comment: @Marged Thanks very helpful. If you could think of any other stuff please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the email addresses, IPs, and URLs mentioned by Marged, you may want to use regexes to look for telephone numbers.

Another common logging mistake is for developers to log usernames and passwords that are passed around (especially if they are in clear text).  These can be for registered users, or internal credentials that you pass to a third party vendor's web service.  So you may want to look for strings like 'username=' or 'password='.

Comment: Thanks and i have implemented username and password. Do you know a way I can track whether there are any address in the log?

Comment: Addresses would be tough to do in general.  If they are U.S. addresses, and they would always log the state abbreviation followed by the zip code, you could try a regex that looked for a valid state followed by a valid 5 or 9 digit zip code.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.  Thanks and happy log parsing!